# Mobile Site Viewing Issue on SmartPhones?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-website

I have developed my site using HTML5,Css3 and JavaScript i put functionality which i want i put the floating point values for fluid desgin which can resize itself. But the problem is that when i check on my system browser it shows fine and when i resize the browser windows it change due to floating values which is fine which i want but when i open the same on my iPod or android device it shows like normal desktop like size it shows small.

Can any one plz suggest me what are the require effort to show my site normal on ipod or smartphone devices like [Yahoo Mobile Site](http://m.yahoo.com) which is normal on desktop and normal on smartphone but my site is normal only on desktop not on smart-devices.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague you don't supply us any code snippets to even look at.

But you will be better using some or other mobile framework like Twitter Bootstrap (not necessarily mobile, but responsive to the max), the jquerymobile framework, or even just use the HTML5 Mobile Boilerplate as a starting point. These already cater for the different mobile devices and viewport sizes out there.

Then you'd also be well of by reading up on resposive design and development methodologies, i.e. using media-queries, percentage widths etc.

Comment: <meta name ="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes, width=device-width" />

It works simply for me gr8 on all the smartDevices ...